# call facebook v3.0 translation but got NNN does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions,

Tags: node.js, facebook

try to Invoke Facebook v3.0 translations service but got exception like this "
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400 - "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'XXXXXX
XXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation ,

and with "type":"GraphMethodException","code":100, "error_subcode":33,

### here is my node-js code

```
const request = require('request-promise');

var uri =  'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/my_app_id/translations?' 
    + 'access_token=my_app_token';

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: uri,
    qs: {
        native_strings: [{"text":"Test String", "description": "This is a test string."}]
    }
};

request(options).then(function (res1) {
            console.log(res1);
            res.write('request done : ' + res1);
            res.end();
}
```

the app token can be obtained via facebook tool explorer

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to pass the access token together with the other POST parameters, not via GET.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your quick response,  I add "access_token : app_token_xxxxx" into the post body, but the result is the same.

Comment: Then I’d suggest you try the request in Graph API Explorer first, to determine whether it is an issue with your specific code or not.

Comment: in FB Explorer , I choose post ->/v3.0/my_appid/translations and add field native_strings with the value, the result is same.

Comment: Hm, not sure what is going on then; suggest you go file a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/